# How to make <img> with clickable link?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I would like to make logo of website clickable to index.html, but whole div is the link. I need only clickable picture.

Here is snippet of my code:

```
<div class="left_header">
    <a href="../index.html">
        <img src="../../images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried different ways to solve this problem but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: All else being equal: Like that. (Your problem might be caused by something about the image (but we can't tell because the URL you used isn't on the public Internet) or some CSS (which you didn't include in the question).

Comment: ["logo" is really poor alt text](https://jkorpela.fi/html/alt.html). The information a logo conveys is usually the identity of the company/other entity the logo is for, not the fact it is a logo (and in this case it is also trying to convey that it is a link to the homepage).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this example working good.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>HTML Image as link</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="left_header">
       <a href="https://www.qries.com/">
           <img src="https://www.qries.com/images/banner_logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
       </a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that is significantly different from the code in the question. Why should this fix whatever problem the OP has?

Comment: Try this code.working 100% sure.

Comment: Your edit (a) still completely lacks any explanation (b) has an "image" that is a 404 error

Comment: image path problem then show image not found 404 error

Comment: That isn't even a coherent sentence. I'm not sure if you're just repeating what I'm saying or trying to blame the OP's original probably on it being a 404 error.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, Try somewhere else. Otherwise don't blame this code, That it doesn't work.

Comment: I never said it didn't work, I said it wasn't significantly different from the code in the question and asked **for an explanation** as to how it solved the problem since it appears to demonstrate that the OP never had a problem in the first place (in which case this can't solve said problem).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250587/discussion-between-p-j-radadiya-and-quentin).

Comment: That doesn't seem like a useful thing to do. Please edit your answer so it explains why the OP's code has the problem they describe and why your code resolves it.

Comment: Ok, that's good. But no more explain this question.